# Returning JSON data as string but getting an error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

The code above query the end point of an API to fetch the bitcoin value for a particular country. That end point returns the value as JSON. I want my function to return the JSON data as string but i am getting the error as "Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'String'".

```
struct CoinManager {

var delegate: CoinManagerDelegate?

let baseURL = "https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTC"
let currencyArray: [String] = ["AUD", "BRL","CAD","CNY","EUR","GBP","HKD","IDR","ILS","INR","JPY","MXN","NOK","NZD","PLN","RON","RUB","SEK","SGD","USD","ZAR"]



mutating func getCoinPrice(currency: String) {






    let urlString = baseURL + currency
    performRequest(urlString: urlString)
    print(urlString)

}


func performRequest(urlString : String) {

       if let url = URL(string: urlString) {

           //2. Create URL session

           let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

           //3. Give session a task


           let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: handle(data:response:error:))

           //4. Start a task
           task.resume()
       }

   }
func handle(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {
    if error != nil {
        delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error!)
        return
    }
    if let safeData = data {
        if let dataString = self.parseJSon(DatA: safeData){
            let dataString1 = String(format: "%.2f", dataString)


            //////////////////////////////////////////
            self.delegate?.didUpdatePrice(price: dataString1, currency: currencyArray)
        }

    }

}

func parseJSon (DatA: Data) -> Double?{

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(CoinData.self, from: DatA)
        let lastPrice = decodedData.last
        print(lastPrice)


        return lastPrice
    } catch {
        delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error)
        return nil
    }

}
```

Comment: What is currency here? What is CoinManagerDelegate? Can you post their info too? And, don’t post your code as an image.

Comment: please post code as text not image

Comment: @Sh_Khan I am a new user in stackoverflow so i will take little time to understand

Comment: you posted a single line of code that defines an array of strings. What do you want as output? A JSON string? You need to be more specific

Comment: @DuncanC yes i want a JSON string . I am new to stackoverflow so facing difficulty to post

Comment: In the previous version of your question you had a lot more code that submitted a network request. Is that part of your question? Are you trying to write code that fetches data from a remote server based on a selected currency code and displays the results?

Comment: @DuncanC thanks for down voting. I am a new user here. anyways, thanks for your answer & contribution. My doubt is solved

Comment: This is a very low quality question. You don't provide a clear description of what you are trying to do. Furthermore, you are not clarifying your question in a meaningful way based on follow-up questions. If you don't want to be down-voted, edit your original question to clearly explain what you are trying to do so that we can help you. You might also post a self-answer that shows the solution you found, so that others can learn. In its current form, your question is confusing and frustrating for all involved, and there isn't really any hope for learning by anyone.

Comment: @DuncanC okay I will look into this. You suggest me how do I edit this question in a proper way ?

Comment: @DuncanC i tried to explain the code through Images, but some people say that not to post image. So i again edited the question

Comment: Provide the code from your original question as formatted code, not as a picture. Explain what you are trying to do. Tell us about the endpoint you are using, and what you expect it to return. ("The code above should query the endpoint `https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indicies/global/ticker/BTC` to fetch the bitcoin value for a particular country. That endpoint returns the result as JSON. I want my function to return that JSON data as a string, but ____ is happening instead.")

Comment: @DuncanC I will edit it. Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Your code access `currency` which doesn't exist in that scrope

```
var currentcurr = ""
func getCoinPrice (currency:String) {
  currentcurr = currency
  //////
}
```

then use `currentcurr` anywhere inside the vc

Comment: where to declare the code? is it in the view controller ?

Comment: you already have `getCoinPrice ` add `var currentcurr = ""` only

Answer (score 0):

It's solved I just added a var with an empty string & assigned my currency data to the new variable which I have declared. Now I am getting JSON data as string.

```
struct CoinManager {
var delegate: CoinManagerDelegate?
var currency1 = ""
let baseURL = "https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/BTC"
let currencyArray: [String] = ["AUD", "BRL","CAD","CNY","EUR","GBP","HKD","IDR","ILS","INR","JPY","MXN","NOK","NZD","PLN","RON","RUB","SEK","SGD","USD","ZAR"]



mutating func getCoinPrice(currency: String) {


      currency1 = currency



    let urlString = baseURL + currency
    performRequest(urlString: urlString)
    print(urlString)

}
```